# How to unit test a class which has field injection (using guice)

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, junit4, guice

Class under test looks like this :

```
public class SomeAdapter {

@Inject
HttpService httpService;

@Inject
Configuration configuration;

public SomeAdapter()
{
    GuiceInjector.getInjector().injectMembers(this);
}

public String getBaseUrl()
{
    return configuration.getProtocol()+ "://" + some.getServer() + ":" + configuration.getPort();
  }
}
```

I have tried InjectMocks from the mockito framework, but it does not seem reliable.Would creating a seperate test module which extends AbstractModule be necessary?

Comment: The class under test is misusing the Guice API (which should not appear anywhere inside your production classes). If the code inside the constructor is removed, then the class should be testable with any mocking library which supports injection of mocked dependencies (such as EasyMock, Mockito, or JMockit).

Comment: @Rogério, So do you mean, the 'GuiceInjector.getInjector().injectMembers(this)' must not appear inside the constructor ?

Comment: Yes, because the whole point of Dependency Injection is to move the code/configuration which is responsible for instantiating dependencies of a class to some separate, external entity (the DI framework/container, and the DI configuration files or classes - "modules" in Guice's case). Production classes themselves should, at most, contain metadata annotations such as `@Inject`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest injecting dependencies outside the class (that would follow single responsibility principle). Then you might use standard Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeAdaptorTest {

  @Inject
  Configuration configuration;

  @InjectMocks
  SomeAdaptor adaptor = new SomeAdaptor();

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    when(configuration.getId()).thenReturn(5);
  }
  ...
```

Or creating another constructor, package private, to accept mocked dependencies.